# How can I remove white spaces INSIDE html tags with a bash command

Tags: bash

I'm having an issue with an html parser program I have.  My html has tags written like `< p>` and `<p >`: the white space is giving me problems.

Is there a simple way to remove these white spaces with something like sed in single bash command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one that trims leading and trailing spaces inside attribute-less tags.

```
$ echo '< p> </ p> <p > < /p>' | sed -E 's|<(/?) *([^ >]*) *>|<\1\2>|g'
<p> </p> <p> </p>
```

Comment: Then feel free to press that ol' check button

Comment: With under 15 reputation, that user can't upvote http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up (so I did it for him).

Answer (score 0):

No, there are too many edge cases where quotes and escaped characters will ruin your results. For every answer you get, there are easy-to-find examples that will break them. See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348) for a complete discussion.